# How to get current category ID

Tags: category, magento-1

I'm trying to display a message just on a certain category page in magento?

I know how to do this on a product page so like:

```
<?php
if (in_array(415, $_product->getCategoryIds())) {?>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#69a740;padding:0 5px;font-size:14px;">Text</span>
<?php } ?>
```

But not sure how to do this on a category page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($category && $category->getId() == 415) { ?>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #69a740; padding: 0 5px; font-size: 14px;">Text</span>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: From your above script, how to put a condition like, cart has only this category of products, if other categories of products available in cart should be an error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

`<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 415) {?>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#69a740;padding:0 5px;font-size:14px;">Text</span>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Using observer how to check current product category id & already cart products category id, if both category id is different trigger observer and show message like You are not allowed to mixed the product. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334 @Ketan